# Billions of rows table as input to Quicksight dataset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

there are two redshift table named `A & B` and a Quicksight dashboard where it takes `A MINUS B`  as query to display content for a visual. If we use DIRECT query option and it is getting timedout because query is not completing in 2 mins(Quicksight have hard limit to run query within 2 mins) .  Is there a way to use such large datasets as input Quicksight dasboard visual ?

Can't use SPICE engine because it have limit 1B or 1TB size limit.Also, it have 15 mins of delay to refresh data.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to provide more information to fully resolve.  MINUS can be a very expensive operation especially if you haven't optimized the tables for this operation.  Can you provide information about your table setup and the EXPLAIN plan of the query you are running?

Barring improving the query, one way to work around a poorly performing query behind quicksight is to move this query to a materialized view.  This way the result of the query can be stored for later retrieval but needs to be refreshed when the source data changes.  It sounds like your data only changes every 15 min (did I get this right?) then this may be an option.

Comment: Tried materialized view. But, once underlying tables have greater than 1B rows then materialized view is taking more than 10 mins to refresh and it is delaying to show latest data in Quicksight.

Comment: Source data changes for every 5 mins and Materialized view is going for full refresh each time .

Comment: As stated, MINUS is an expensive operation.  More info will be needed to help improve the query.  What are the sort and dist keys on the tables?   Are there any primary keys?  Is only a subset of columns needed to determine "sameness"?  Are all the columns fed into the MINUS operation?